# Does an online tool exist that can find words of a certain length given an input of certain characters?

Tags: online-resources

Can anyone think of a tool with which I can pass it many optional parameters such as the length of the word I'm looking for, and a few letters in that word and have it spit out a list of words?

Comment: Is this for cheating at crosswords?

Comment: Or at Scrabble?

Comment: No, it's for solving some very difficult analogies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you understand regexs, you can use [this](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/intro.html).

For example, '^mo.s.$' yields:

- moist
- moose
- mosso
- mossy
- mouse
- mousy

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! That website is awesome I am a web developer so I know a little regexp but who's afraid to learn a little more!

Comment: I'm trying to find 7 letter words using [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]{7} but it's coming up with all lengths of words. It works fine on a text file but not the website. Any tips?

Comment: @CreativiTimothy -- not *all* lengths, all lengths greater than or equal to 7.  You need to match the beginning and end, like this *^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]{7}$*

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [More Words](http://www.morewords.com/).

Here are some basic word search options:

> Use a hyphen (dash) to give the location of a missing letter: w-rd or -are
>   Use an asterisk (star) for any number of unknown letters: lett* or *gry or ar*ct
>   Exclude words containing the letters that follow a caret (hat): ma-e ^kt
>   Or enter a few letters (without hyphens or asterisks) to see if they make any words.