# Where can I find a relatively inclusive word-list for analysis of prefixes and suffixes?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes, prefixes, dictionaries, resources

To illustrate a simple example, when I encounter the word "claustrophobia", what I already knew is the left part "claustro-" means "small and enclosed", and I want to discover if "-phobia" has a fixed meaning of "fear". So if I have a word-list, I can search all the words that has "-phobia" and look up their meanings to confirm my guess.

Perhaps there are other reasons I need a word-list. For example, I sometimes want to discover questions like which words has the form "*xxyyzz*" (like bookkeeper) or which words has the part "ijk" (Dijkstra).

I've found a few word-lists but they are too small to include more complicated words like names of famous person and places, technical terms or obscure words.

Comment: I think this is a little bit too broad, as well as general reference

Comment: I think that ultimately you are actually looking for a dictionary/encyclopedia which can be searched using regular expressions.

Comment: is this what you ask?http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23322/does-an-online-tool-exist-that-can-find-words-of-a-certain-length-given-an-input

Comment: That's a good suggestion @Bogdan

Answer (score 3):

I think [the Regex Dictionary](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/) (as Bogdan Lataianu suggested) is pretty much fine for my requirements. It accepts regular expressions and searches in the *American Heritage Dictionary*, which has a sufficient number of words.